# Filling Word Fields from a .DAT file with VBA

Tags: vba, import, ms-word, field, bookmarks

I'm working with a Java application that is going to write a `.dat` file that is supposed to be used as a template to fill a `Word` template that has `fields` and `bookmarks` in it.  I've spent quite awhile searching for information on `.dat` files being used to template a Word `field/bookmark` and I've yet to come up with anything.

I have the VBA code written to go and get the file, but I have two large problems that I can't seem to locate the answer to. I'd appreciate if someone could answer the following:

1. What should the `.dat` file code look like?  (not the code to
   generate it, have that, but how should it be formatted to achieve the desired result)
2. After I open the `.dat` file with `VBA`, do I need to do anything
   code-wise to have it replace the `fields/bookmarks` with its data?

Currently I do have the code to go out and get the `.dat` file and open it.  I have code written to do inserts for bookmarks and fields, but seeing as how I wasn't sure if there was a specific structure to`.dat` files for `vba` to read, I didn't know if it was pertinent or not.  Thank you to Jean-François Corbett and Roman for clarifying this.

Taking this into consideration, I've decided to use the following `.dat` file format.

```
File.dat
RequisitionHeader_requisitionNumber=11-2019
RequisitionHeader_poNumber=889-0936
RequisitionHeader_orderDate=11/12/1901
```

With that, using the `VBA` I have now that opens the file, do I need to write a text parser inside of `VBA` to find and replace values into the corresponding field/bookmarkName?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What do you mean by `.dat` file?! `.dat` is just a generic extension that people use for all kinds of different things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now one can understand better. So you have already code to loop through bookmarks and fields and put values in it, and your problem is to know how you can read data from a file with VBA.
Please keep in mind that VBA is nothing else then an Visual Basic 6.0 integrated in an Office application. So accessing files is restricted to the old Basic I/O procedures. You can find first information [here](http://mc-computing.com/languages/visualbasic/vbfileio.htm%20/%22here%22).
On the other hand, while working with VBA you can always use the Windows Scripting Host to read all lines of a text file into memory/into a variable, like this:

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(FileName) Then
   Set f=fso.OpenTextFile(FileName,1)
   Content=f.ReadAll
   f.close
   (rest ommitted)
```

Afterwards you're free to parse your text as you like it, e.g. using the Split function to convert all lines first into an array, and then to get the values from each line.

There's also the old approach to use the functions related to INI files; you may find this in some old handbooks. Here you should keep in mind that the Windows API function for INI files don't read more than 256 characters after the = sign.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to understand the datastructure of the input data (in the .dat file - is it text data or binary data, what are the logical patterns after which the data is modelled), then find a good way to read the data (open the file in vba, locate and access the relevant data in the file from vba), maybe you will then have to validate the data (check for data integrity, format etc.) and finally fill in the data into the fields in the word document.

As pointed out by Jean-François Corbett before: Unless you provide some insight into what you are working with only general answers are possible.